# Viewing dynamaically generated code

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I **view** the code that I have **dynamically** created with **jquery/Javascript?**

Comment: What code? How are you dynamically creating it? Are you sure you mean "code" and not "DOM structures"?

Comment: Could be also DOM structure :-) I mean the generated output when I create an element.

Answer (score 1):

In most browsers, right-clicking on a page, and clicking "Inspect Element" will let you view the markup of said page.

This markup will include any that was generated using JavaScript and/or jQuery.

Note: *Due to the lack of detail in the question, I assumed that you wanted to view the markup of a page, after it was rendered by the browser.*

**Edit**: Please see [Quentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37008469/6052290), as they provided links to information about the developer tools provided with some major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery's [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function:

```
$("div.someClass").text(code_to_display);
```

Comment: Is there a way to se it in a browser (add On)?

Comment: you can use console.log(code_to_display) to display it in the Chrome dev tool's console for example

Comment: I tested Mozilla and the Web Developer Toolbar. There is "Button" with Show generated code, but it doesn't show it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "myDiv";
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Look at the `Elements` tab in Chrome Dev Tools (or similar in other browsers) and scroll to the bottom of the `<body></body>` tag to see the new element.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers have developer tools, which include a DOM inspector, built-in. They can usually be triggered by selecting something along the lines of "Inspect Element" from the context menu inside the viewport.

- [Opera](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/)
- [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/)
- [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools)
- [Edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/f12-devtools-guide/)
- [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)